# MS Windows Data Center Graphics Card Drivers

Tags: windows, server, graphics, driver

Any thoughts on why developers have not created graphics drivers for advanced cards, for MS Windows server software like Data Center 2019? Do graphics drivers present insurmountable security issues? I can only get vga to work and have tried several graphics cards from advanced to simple. Thank you.

Comment: wrong site for this... maybe https://superuser.com/ ?